# Android data-binding with recycler view

Tags: android, database, android-fragments, data-binding, android-recyclerview

I would like to implement "new" data binding in my app, but I'm stuck. I have a database where I save the contacts, so I need to take data from another fragment and show them in the recycler view. 
SO: fragment with recycler view -> click on AddButton -->open new fragment with editTexts -> fill the editTexts -> save to database -> show in previous fragment (with that recycler view)
I've done Adapter but I don't know ho to set it in my fragment. Could you help me please?

Model

```
public class Contact extends SugarRecord {

    public String name;
    private String number;
    private String email;
    private boolean isFavourite;

    public Contact() {
    }

    public Contact(String name, String email, String number, Boolean isFavourite) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.number = number;
        this.isFavourite = isFavourite;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void setFavourite(Boolean isFavourite) {
        this.isFavourite = isFavourite;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    @Bindable
    public boolean getFavourite() {
        return isFavourite;
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class ContactsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsRecyclerAdapter.BindingHolder> {
    private List<Contact> mContacts;


    public static class BindingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ViewDataBinding binding;

        public BindingHolder(View rowView) {
            super(rowView);
            binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(rowView);
        }
         public ViewDataBinding getBinding() {
             return binding;
         }
    }

    public ContactsRecyclerAdapter(List<Contact> recyclerUsers) {
        this.mContacts = recyclerUsers;
    }

    @Override
    public BindingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int type) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_contact, parent, false);
        BindingHolder holder = new BindingHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BindingHolder holder, int position) {
        final Contact contact = mContacts.get(position);
        holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.contact, contact);
        holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContacts.size();
    }
}
```

Fragment where I want the recycler view

```
public class ContactListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String NEWCONTACT = "newcontact";

    FloatingActionButton fabButton;
    SearchView searchView;

    public static ContactListFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        ContactListFragment fragment = new ContactListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_list, container, false);


        return view;
    }
----- other stuff in the fragment ------
```

Comment: update your contacts list in onResume() method of previous fragment, then call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter.

Comment: Could you describe it in detail please?

Comment: You have to update newly created contact in your mContacts(i.e., List<Contact>)object.

Comment: OK, thanks. And where to call notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: after updating  contacts object,call notifyDataSetChanged() immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialise `RecyclerView` in `onCreateView` method of `ContactListFragment` like below

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_list, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    if(recyclerView != null) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ContactsRecyclerAdapter(recyclerUsers));
    }
```

this way you can set adapter to recycler view in fragment.